# Can't hide items within ToolbarItemGroup, disappears on iPhone

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a view with a set of toolbar items where I sometimes want to hide some of the items when activating a certain state.

Consider the following SwiftUI code:

```
@State var hideToolbarItems = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationSplitView {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .navigationTitle("MyToolbarItems")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        hideToolbarItems.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Toggle")
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    if !hideToolbarItems {
                        Button {
                        } label: {
                            Text("Button1")
                        }
                        Button {
                        } label: {
                            Text("Button2")
                        }
                        Button {
                        } label: {
                            Text("Button3")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    } detail: {
    }
}
```

When previewing this it seems to work as expected, the `ToolbarItemGroup` disappears when `hideToolbarItems` becomes `true` and appears again when `hideToolbarItems` is `false`. On an iPad device it works almost the same, the `ToolbarItemGroup` becomes grouped under a "..."-icon until the `hideToolbarItems` has changed back and forth, then it won't become grouped under a "..."-icon anymore.
But the real problem is that the `ToolbarItemGroup` won't show at all on an iPhone device. Has anyone solved this problem on iPhone? I can't seem to find a good solution.

I am running Xcode 14.2 and use iOS 16.0.

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI effects different result by platforms.
ToolbarItemGroup may be compact button only in iPad.
if you want to show buttons as compact anytime, you can use Menu.

```
ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
    if !hideToolbarItems {
        Menu {
            Button {
            } label: {
                Text("Button1")
            }
            Button {
            } label: {
                Text("Button2")
            }
            Button {
            } label: {
                Text("Button3")
            }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually makes the menu appear again on iPhone which is great, thanks! The problem I am left with now is that iOS sometimes bundles the Menu together with the lonely ToolbarItem if space is tight and creates its own ellipsis-circle. When tapping this ellipsis circle the Menu-section looks a bit weird, just an empty row.
There is also some weird behavior when presenting a sheet on the view, then an extra ellipsis circle appears with no content, but I might be able to live with that until Apple gets their stuff right I guess...